# is it possible to update parent object field with specific child object record field?

Tags: trigger, process-builder

Can we use process builder or trigger to update parent object field called Date1 with specific child record name and type occupancy deadline date whenever deadline date is added on child record name and type  called Occupancy ?

Is it possible with `Process Builder`? I tried process builder but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can update. Refer the below example to solve your issue.

**Step 1** : Select Child Object & Related functionality

[image]

**Step 2** : Set criteria for execution

[image]

**Step 3** : Select parent record and update record

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is feasible. As with the Process Builder we can Update any related records.

Steps as below.

1. Create a Process builder on child object
2. Add Criteria with Child Object field saying ,

   Field : Deadline

   Operator : IsChanged

   Value : True
3. Add Action as,

   Action type : Update Records

   Record Type : [Parent Object Name]
4. In the Set New Fields section, Select

   Field = Parent Deadline Date

   Type = Reference

   Value = Childs DeadLine Date

The same goes with the other fields mapping.

--
Regards

Sharan Desai